# jstree disable callbacks when needed

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, jstree

I have generated a tree view of my bucket files, whenever I add/rename/delete a node(file or folder) I use the callback to do the changes in s3 but let say a file upload fails then in the callback of the ajax call I delete the node but it triggers the delete callback so is there a way I can disable the callback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just explain anything rather than doing a downvote ?

Comment: hey there.  can you update you tree after you get successful ajax response and not before that?  that way on failure you just don't do anything